# rdlc paper size returns always portrait

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a simple local rdlc where the page units=in, orientation=landscape and paper size=A4 w=11.69 h=8.27

When I try to retrieve the reports papersize by using

```
var paperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettigs().PaperSize;
```

I get the following returned {[PaperSize A4 Kind=A4 Height=1169 Width=827]}

What I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong.

As can be seen from the msdn link below:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Height and Width values are returned in hundredths of an inch.

Check if PaperSize.IsLandscape return true

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim ps As New PageSettings()            'Declare a new PageSettings for printing
    ps.Landscape = True                     'Set True for landscape, False for Portrait
    ps.Margins = New Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)    'Set margins

    'Choose paper size from the paper sizes defined in ur printer.
    'Here we use Linq to quickly choose by name
    ps.PaperSize = (From p In ps.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes Where p.PaperName = "A4").First()

    'Alternatively you can set the paper size as custom
    'ps.PaperSize = new PaperSize("MyPaperSize", 827, 1169);
    ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(ps)

    ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)

    'Refresh the report
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```